# не работает pip в виртуальной среде

Tags: python, django, pip

Вот  мои шаги:

```
pyhon -m venv venv
venv\scripts\activate
pip install django==4.2.9
```

После этого мне выдают ошибку:

> Fatal error in launcher: Failed to find shebang

Даже, если просто в `cmd` написать `pip` , то будет ошибка. 
`Pip` обновлял, не помогло.

Comment: Это полный текст ошибки?

Comment: Попробуйте python3 -m pip. Или python переустановите